# Inline option elements inside Select using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want inline Select option elements because there is alot of data and it would be nicer if option elements are inline with width of select element.

Since I am using multiselect bootstrap plugin, al Select elements are converted to lists.

What I have:

[image: Screenshot 1]

And this is whant I want to achieve

[image: Screenshot 2]

My question is can I inline Select option elements using bootstrap?

This is original HTML CODE:

```
<select id="food" multiple="multiple" class="mutlival">
                                <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
                                <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
                                <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
                                <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
                                <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
                                <option value="onions">Onions</option>
                            </select>
```

And after bootstrap does his magic, as output I got this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="None selected">
    None selected 
    <b class="caret">
    </b>
  </button>
  <ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
    <li class="multiselect-item multiselect-all">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="multiselect-all">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="multiselect-all">
          Select all
        </label>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="cheese">
          Cheese
        </label>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="tomatoes">
          Tomatoes
        </label>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="mozarella">
          Mozzarella
        </label>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="mushrooms">
          Mushrooms
        </label>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="pepperoni">
          Pepperoni
        </label>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="onions">
          Onions
        </label>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: don't understand what do you mean under "inline" here. Do you want to show all options in one row?

Comment: @demo I updated my question so it's clear now what I want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question properly I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/ec1469e1/

Basically what I did was target the `ul` and get rid of the absolute positioning (bootstrap default) and give it a percentage based width. Then all you have to do is tell the `li` item to be `inline-block` and everything look nice!

```
ul.multiselect-container.dropdown-menu {
  width: 70%;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
}

ul.multiselect-container.dropdown-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Didn't see your image example. Here is how you would do it using flex box (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

EDIT 2: Have a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e9pmcj6g/2/

So, try applying this css:

```
ul.multiselect-container.dropdown-menu {
    height: 9em; // 3 times the height of your li elements
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}

ul.multiselect-container.dropdown-menu li {
    height: 2em;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. You first code worked but there was problem because dropdown was already triggered. Your edited code is not working. It doesn't inline all checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/bxo5qcbq/ (very poor example)

So just add classes to your options. In my case i add Bootstrap classes `pull-left` and `pull-right`.

To make next "row" - add empty option or option with separator.

```
<option value="1" class="pull-left">Val 1</option>
<option value="2" class="pull-right">Val 2</option>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I want to make responsive select so I new rows needs to be added automaticlly